# Proving that a specific gamma function is a guaranteed lower bound for a factorial function

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, factorial, gamma-function

In reviewing [Ramanujan's proof](http://www.zyymat.com/ramanujans-proof-of-bertrands-postulate.html) of Bertrand's postulate, Ramanujan observes that:

$$\ln\Gamma(x) - 2\ln\Gamma(\frac{x+1}{2}) \le \ln(\lfloor{x}\rfloor!) - 2\ln(\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\rfloor!)$$

I have noticed that under some circumstances, the following lower bound is better.

$$\ln\Gamma(x) - 2\ln\Gamma(\frac{x+1}{2}) \le \ln\Gamma(x+1) - 2\ln\Gamma(\frac{x+2}{2}) \le \ln(\lfloor{x}\rfloor!) - 2\ln(\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\rfloor!)$$

For example, this is true when $x=34$.  I'm assuming that it is not true in all cases or Ramanujan would have used the tighter lower bound in his proof.

How can I show that $\ln\Gamma(x) - 2\ln\Gamma(\frac{x+1}{2})$ is guaranteed to be lower in all cases $x \ge 2$ and identify the conditions when $\ln\Gamma(x+1) - 2\ln\Gamma(\frac{x+2}{2})$ is the better lower bound?

Here's my thinking on this question:

- $\ln\Gamma(x-1) - 2\ln\Gamma(\frac{x}{2})$ is an increasing function (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/361996/48606))
- There are some [known conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/360174/48606) when $\ln\Gamma(x-1) - 2\ln\Gamma(\frac{x}{2}) \le \ln\Gamma(\lfloor{x}\rfloor+1) - 2\ln\Gamma(\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\rfloor+1)$
- My goal with this question is to show the conditions when $\ln\Gamma(x+1) - 2\ln\Gamma(\frac{x+2}{2}) \le \ln(\lfloor{x}\rfloor!) - 2\ln\Gamma(\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\rfloor!)$ and when it is not.

Thanks very much,

-Larry

Comment: "I'm assuming that it is not true in all cases or Ramanujan would have used the tighter lower bound in his proof." I don't know about your example, but this isn't true in general. If a simpler approximation is sufficient for a given situation then people often don't clutter up their work with extra terms. Years ago when I suggested some miniscule corrections to an approximation, my supervisor responded "We're not trying to build a high-precision bomb, we're trying to understand something."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove $f(x)\leq g(x) \leq h(x)$, where:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \ln\Gamma(x) - 2\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right),\\
g(x) &= \ln\Gamma(x+1) - 2\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{x+2}{2}\right),\\
h(x) &= \ln\left( \lfloor{x}\rfloor! \right) - 2\ln\left( \left\lfloor\frac{x}{2} \right\rfloor!\right).
\end{align}

Firstly, this is only true for $x\in \mathbb{N}$ with $x\geq 2$. For $x=1$ we have:
\begin{align}
g(1) &= \ln\Gamma(2) - 2\ln\Gamma\left(3/2\right)\\
     &= 2\ln(2) - \ln(\pi)\\
     &= 0.24\ldots\\
h(1) &= \ln\left( 1 \right) - 2\ln\left( 1 \right)\\
     &= 0,
\end{align}
so g(1) > h(1). For $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)>h(x)$ infinitely often.

Secondly, note that for even $x$, $g(x)=h(x)$.

Finally, for odd $x\geq 3$, you can prove $h(x)>g(x)$ by comparing term-by term, and noting that $\Gamma(x/2 + 1)$ is monotonic in this regime ($\Gamma(x)$ has a single minimum at $x=1.46\ldots$).

Comparing $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is a bit simpler and I'll leave it out for now.

Comment: Hi Douglas, I am interested in $x \in  \mathbb{R}$ where $x \ge 2$.  I am especially interested under what conditions $g(x) > h(x)$ and also the reasoning to show that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ where $x \ge 2$, $f(x) \le h(x)$.  Thanks.

Comment: @Larry In your question you say (in terms of my notation) that Ramanujan observed $f(x) \leq h(x)$ and that you want to prove $g(x) \leq h(x)$.  So I'm surprised to hear you say now that you want to prove $f(x) \leq h(x)$!

Comment: @Larry Regarding the sign of $h(x)-g(x)$, we have $h(x)<g(x)\ \forall x \in (n,n+1)$, for every $n\geq 2$ an even integer, and $h(x)\geq g(x)\ \forall x \in [n,n+1]$ for every $n\geq 3$ an odd integer.  You should plot the difference of these two functions.

Comment: Thanks, Douglas!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  I'm sorry if my interest in $f(x) \le h(x)$ wasn't clear.  I tried to make this second question clear when I wrote: "How can I show that $\ln\Gamma(x)-2\ln\Gamma(\frac{x+1}{2})$ is guaranteed to be lower in all cases $x \ge 2$."